# How to set email notification for periodical build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a job that sends email to user that triggered build (`to: "$BUILD_USER_EMAIL"`) after successful build. After I set periodical job execution I got an exception:

```
Error when executing failure post condition:
Also:   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.actions.ErrorAction$ErrorId: e1a1a304-2fee-437a-9478-329b84c46e4b
hudson.AbortException: Email not sent. No recipients of any kind specified ('to', 'cc', 'bcc').
    ...
```

cause there is actually no user that triggers the job since Jenkins run it by itself. So what would be the best option to make it work?

Comment: "Periodical build" is not triggered by user, but rather by scheduler. Who do you think the mail should go to? Also, some code could help.

Comment: `email: BUILD_USER_EMAIL ?: 'default@mail.com'`